# XSLT transformation substitution element to attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

Given an `<item>`, I would like to extract an element's value, translate it to a given corresponding value and insert it as an attribute value alongside a value from a second element.

I have the following XML (trimmed excessive tags, namespace etc):

```
<items>
  <item>
    <title>Test Title</title>
    <date>Sun, 26 Feb 2012 08:25:20 +0000</date>
    <creator>hsimah</creator>
    <description>Test description</description>
    <content>Test content here.</content>
    <post_id>351</post_id>
    <post_name>test-title</post_name>
    <status>publish</status>
    <post_parent>245</post_parent>
  </item>
</items>
```

And I require it to be in the following format (**NB translated_post_parent**):

```
<Container>
  <Data>
    <Item Id="{translated_post_parent}/test-title" Status="publish" />
    <Route Alias="{translated_post_parent}/test-title" />
    <Details Owner="hsimah" />
    <Title Title="Test Title" />
  </Data>
</Container>
```

My in-progress XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
  <Container>
    <xsl:for-each select ="items/item">
      <Data>
        <Item Id="{post_name}" Status="{status}">
        <Route Alias="{post_name}" />
        <Details Owner="{creator}" />
        <Title Title="{title}" />
      </Data>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </Container>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So far so good. But what I need to do now is convert the `post_parent` to a new corresponding value. I have a list of the translated values and have written a template as such:

```
<xsl:template match="post_parent/text()[.='245']">
  <TestPart Container="NewValue" />
</xsl:template>
```

With this added to the `<Data>` payload:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="post_parent" />
```

Which results in:

```
<TestPart Container="NewValue" />
```

What I cannot figure out is how to get that value into the attributes required (`Id` in the `<Item>` and `Alias` in the `<Route>`) alongside a reference to the value in `<post_name>`. What I need, simply, is:

```
<TestPart Container="NewValue/{post_name}" />
```

Where `<post_parent>` was `245` (and is now `NewValue`).

Comment: "*I have a list of the translated values*" Where is this list and what does it look like? Please add it your question - and show us the **exact** output you expect to get.

Comment: @michael.hor257k thanks for the comment. The translated value is largely irrelevant, it's the process of translating and concatenating the two elements' values that I need help with. har07 has given me a perfect solution already.

Comment: "*har07 has given me a perfect solution*" Shrug. Good for you. I still don't understand the question. Esp. the part where you hard-code the `245` value.

Comment: The item is exported from one system with an ID (eg 245) and will be imported into a new system with a new ID, whatever that may be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `post_name` is preceding-sibling of `post_parent` in the XML posted, you can use `preceding-sibling` axis to get it from current `post_parent` context :

```
<xsl:template match="post_parent[.='245']">
  <TestPart Container="NewValue/{preceding-sibling::post_name}" />
</xsl:template>
```

or if the order of appearance of `post_name` and `post_parent` is arbitrary, you can go up one level to the parent element first and then down again to get the corresponding `post_name` :

```
<xsl:template match="post_parent[.='245']">
  <TestPart Container="NewValue/{parent::*/post_name}" />
</xsl:template>
```

**<kbd>[`xsltransform.net demo`](http://xsltransform.net/ncdD7mK/1)</kbd>**

As an aside, your `<xsl:for-each select ="items/item">` can be replaced with `xsl:apply-templates` along with `<xsl:template match="items/item">`. Using templates is considered more natural approach in XSLT compared to foreach loop.

Comment: Legend. That is exactly what I needed to know. I've only started with XSLT today so am learning the ropes slowly. A quick follow up: Will I have to create a template for every `post_parent` value (sample is 245, but there will be a dozen or so) or is there a faster way to do the replacement (e.g. key-value situation)?

Comment: Nevermind, I googled and came across a sample of exactly what I need. Thanks again.